# Split a string at a delimiter and sum the last field

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file of strings:

```
XC:a:1
XC:b:2
XC:c:0
```

and so on. I want to split it at the second `:` and sum all the integers. For example, for the above list I want to do `1+2+0+...`

I tried `cut -d ":"` but it gives only the field `XC`.

Comment: No, they are in different rows

Comment: If my answer seemed helpful below, do mark the answer _accepted_ with a `^` for the answer, so that this post can be made useful for somebody visiting in the future

Answer (score 1):

If you have perl installed; you could do this in one line.

```
perl -F/:/ -ane 'END {print "$x\n"} $x += $F[2]' inputFile

-F/:/  sets colon as the split separator works with -a
-a     autosplit mode with -n splits each line into @F
-n     assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` and `paste` this way:

```
 paste -s -d+ <(cut -f3 -d: file) | bc
```

- `<(cut ...)` => uses process substitution to send the extracted numbers to `paste`
- `paste -s -d+` => converts numbers on multiple lines to this format `1+2+3` which is then fed to `bc` for math

Comment: Seems cleaner to do `cut -f3 -d: file | paste -s -d+ - | bc`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using awk, try this one or you can replace $NF with the column number.

> awk -F: '{sum+=$NF} END { print sum}'  file_name

Answer (score 0):

Using Python:

```
python -c "print(sum(int(line.split(':')[-1]) for line in open('filename')))"
```